# Makefile: $(CC) isn't working with ifeq

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, cc

So, this is odd. In my makefile I have

```
CC:=icc
ifeq ($(CC),icc)
CFLAGS := $(ICCFLAGS)
LIBS := $(LIBS) -openmp
else
CFLAGS := $(GCCFLAGS)
LIBS := $(LIBS) -fopenmp
endif
```

for make, the condition is false but

```
CCC:=icc
ifeq ($(CCC),icc)
CFLAGS := $(ICCFLAGS)
LIBS := $(LIBS) -openmp
else
CFLAGS := $(GCCFLAGS)
LIBS := $(LIBS) -fopenmp
endif
```

here the condition is true, and

```
CC:=icc
CCC:=$(CC)
ifeq ($(CCC),icc)
CFLAGS := $(ICCFLAGS)
LIBS := $(LIBS) -openmp
else
CFLAGS := $(GCCFLAGS)
LIBS := $(LIBS) -fopenmp
endif
```

here the condition is false again. What the hell is going on?

Comment: Try putting `$(info CC is $(CC))` at different places in the makefile (e.g. at the very top, just before `CC := icc`, just *after* `CC := icc`). That will give us a better idea of where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that you're either passing `CC` as a command line option, like:

```
make CC=...
```

... or invoking make with `-e` switch, which forces environment variables to take precedence over the ones defined in Makefile.

You can use [`origin` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Origin-Function) to check how the variable has been defined:

```
CC := icc
$(error CC comes from $(origin CC))
```

If this prints `command line` or `environment override`, then the solution is to use [`override` directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive):

```
override CC := icc
```

This will set `CC` variable even if there is another one from command line or environment.

Comment: It says *** CC comes from file.  Stop.

Comment: well, using override solved the issue but I don't understand where CC is changed